# Bulk insert with 2 delimiters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a flat file in which the delimiter is the field surrounded by " ".

ie. "field1" "field2" ...

Does MS SQL support this type of delimiter. I suspect I'll be parsing the file and making a CSV file, but figured I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL won't support this format.  You will need to create a CSV file, but Excel should do this automatically.